# LDAP Query View Errors for RSS

Tags: views, 7, feeds, authentication-authorization

I'm trying to add an RSS feed to a LDAP Query view, but I keep getting and error message.

"***Row style plugin requires specifying which views fields to use for RSS item.***"

Is there a way to show an RSS feed from LDAP in Views?

UPDATED WITH IMAGE

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAP lets you query an LDAP service, create a View of an ldap query, process an ldap result using Feeds, or import/update Users to your site.

An RSS view, provided by [Views RSS](http://drupal.org/project/views_rss), is simply a contributed View type from a community module. You must tell [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) what `fields` should show up in the RSS feed you're creating. Typically there is a `Settings` option next to the `Row Style` to set what fields to display.

See the attached settings options (which is using an LDAP Query View). You need to make your LDAP Query first using the [LDAP module](http://drupal.org/project/ldap), then add a new `Display Type` of type `Feed` in Views and then configure the `Fields` settings for the RSS feed.

[image]

Comment: I added an image to show you where I'm having the problem from where I start creating the view.

Comment: Yup. ok try to follow me. Your making a Page with a "Feed" in 1 admin page from "Add View". Look at my screenshot, It 3 tabs on the left: Page, Feed and +Add.  You need to make an LDAP View that is just a Page 1st. Then press "Add Display" in that 1 view and add a "Feed" display. You can't make it all in the initial View config page you're using. You need to make a page first, then add a new Feed display.

Comment: O.K.  I got it now. :)  Thanks for the help. 

I tried to vote up on the reputation but I'm at a low level that I can't.